# Notepad++ RegEx to only capture text without certain preceding word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to write a Notepad++ RegEx that will find and highlight all instances of my the text "`\r\n`" in my text document that are not prefaced with the word "`</column>`".

For example I would want to find and highlight "`\r\n`" in the lines  "`abc\r\n`" and "`123##@\r\n`", but not in the line "`</column>\r\n`".

What would this RegEx be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight just the `\r\n`, this should work:

```
(?<!</column>)\r\n
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I may not have made it clear, but I would only like the highlight the \r\n portion of the text though. When I use your regex, it doesn't filter out lines portions of text with </column> preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that does the job:

Find what: `^(?!.*</column>\R).+\R`

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
(?!             : start negative lookahead, make sure we have not:
    .*          : 0 or more any character
    </column>   : literally </column>
    \R          : any kind of line break
)               : end lookahead
.+              : 1 or more any character
\R              : any kind of line break
```

Comment: That almost exactly what I'm looking for, but I only want to highlight the \r\n portion of the text. I edited my question probably after you started looking into this.